# I'm Creating multiplication table. need help creating new line between each loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Hey so I was assigned a homework assignment where I have to create a multiplication table that reads like the picture attached

[image: wanted output]

so I've tried console.log on both loops but this leads to a mess of numbers. I've tried putting "\n" in each one

```
var insideN = " "
for (var n = 1; n <= 9; n++) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++ ,) {
        insideN += (n * i) + "\n";
    }
}
```

My expected result was to make it look like a nice multiplication table.

Answer (score 5):

You need to concatenate `\n` in the outer loop, not the inner loop. The inner loop should separate the numbers with spaces.

```js
var insideN = ""
for (var n = 1; n <= 9; n++) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (n * i < 10) {
      insideN += " "; // for alignment
    }
    insideN += (n * i) + " ";
  }
  insideN += "\n";
}

console.log(insideN);
```